# how to Get Number Of Users Online for each role using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, security, asp.net-membership

I would like to know the number of users logged for each role into my ASP.NET application 
i have an (Admin) role and the (rest) role
i want to know the Number Of Users Online for each one not the entire application what this method did :

```
Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enumerate the users yourself.  If you make use of

```
Membership.GetAllUsers()
```

you get a collection of all available users.  Then you can loop through each user and check the `IsOnline` property to see if the user is online.  To determine the roles of the user, you can make use of the methods in the [**`Roles`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx) class.

For example, if you have two roles `admin` and `rest`, and you would like to display how many users are online in each role, you could do something like this:

```
var adminCount = 0, restCount = 0;
foreach ( var user in Membership.GetAllUsers().Where(u => u.IsOnline) )
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "admin"))
        adminCount++;
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "rest"))
        restCount++;

// do something with adminCount and restCount
```

If you have more complicated role structure, or many roles, you could use a map to store the count per role.  The logic is up to you what you want to accomplish, this should provide all the pieces necessary to express your custom counting logic.

Comment: Hi mellamokb,  thank you for reply, will look further into this

Comment: can you please be more specific

Comment: yes yes duddy understood ,   tnks
can you explain this ligne ((((   Membership.GetAllUsers().Where(u => u.IsOnline)   ))) i'm using VB

Comment: That is LINQ code to filter out only the users that are online.  It can be accomplished the same way with an if statement: `foreach (var user in Membership.GetAllUsers()) { if (user.IsOnline) { /* Same logic here */ } }`, if you are not familiar with LINQ or don't have access to use it.

Comment: that's it tnnkssssssssssssssssss ^^ problem was solved
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim GIAC As Int16 = 0
        Dim u As Int16 = 0
        For Each user In Membership.GetAllUsers()
            If user.IsOnLine Then
                If Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "GIAC") Or Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "GIAC-Administrateurs") Then
                    GIAC += 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        lblCountEnLigne.Text = GIAC.ToString()
    End Sub

Comment: please  mellamokb just an another question : I would like to make tow LoginUrl in my choice note just one : and i'm so sorry fr my bad english language  ^^
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms name="nomCookie" loginUrl="GIAC.aspx" timeout="90"/>
    </authentication>